# WCF basic256 message encryption over HTTPS

Tags: .net, wcf, security, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt the message with basic256 encryption and send it over HTTPS in WCF using basicHttpBinding? I know there is a security mode called TransportWithMessageCredentials but it expects a clientCredentialType for message and "none" is not an option. Also, do all the basic256 algorithms (AES 256) use passkeys in WCF? if so, how do we know the length of those passkeys? if not, can we specify the passkey of a specified length? Is it configurable?

Comment: so, I've been following this article to implement custom encryption/decryption http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=166044 However, I'm getting a cryptographic error saying bad data when the server tries to decrypt the message. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also, is it possible to provide an independent key for AES encryption that will be a shared secret between the client and the server and won't be transmitted over the wire instead of using a randomly generated key?